# How to implement IIS authentication in an asp.net web api project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I've been tasked with enabling authentication and authorization for our project's api. The main goal is to protect the methods from misuse, however we also need to enable a developer from another company to call the methods in their code.

Being new to authentication and authorization I'm overwhelmed with the many different options available for .NET etc. Some techniques look promising until you read that they pass credentials in plain text (basic auth?) or have other issues etc... I'm just looking for a reliable and safe approach.

I'm using IIS to host the web api, and I have seen that one such option is to authenticate at the 'host level'. My supervisor has mentioned this is the preferred approach.

I have looked at many threads and videos regarding authenticating in IIS. From what I can work out, such a solution alerts the user that a certain action requires authentication and to enter their credentials.

My issues are as follows:

- Given the other developer is not a member of our domain, how can they authenticate using their (windows?) credentials. Is there an alternative to windows authentication?
- How will requiring authorization on certain api actions impact the function of the site normally? I.e. will I have to pass valid credentials to the api in my code, for each request?

Overall I'm just a bit uncertain on how this all works and I appreciate any advice given.

Comment: An app that they are writing needs to access the API? What kind of app is it? I feel your pain here, but this question is somewhat too broad as it stands.

Comment: may I suggest looking into [IdentityServer4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/) where you can protect your resources (API) by requiring authorization. This [tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/01/23/asp-net-core-authentication-with-identityserver4/) will probably help too

Comment: @spender Essentially they are working on a user registration page and some components of the interface will populate via calls to our API.

Comment: "pass credentials in plain text " is not necessarily a terrible issue if you use SSL (i.e. use HTTPS) to encrypt your connection

Comment: "Given the other developer is not a member of our domain, how can they authenticate using their (windows?) credentials. "...you can use ADFS to create a trust between your domain and theirs and create an SSO environment that way. Or you can use a totally separate identity system, based on OAuth or something. Software such as IdentityServer and modern versions of ADFS can generate OAuth tokens. There are a number of possibilities.

Comment: "How will requiring authorization on certain api actions impact the function of the site normally? I.e. will I have to pass valid credentials to the api in my code, for each request?" depends on the auth system...in basic auth yes they do. If you use a token-based service e.g. Windows Auth, Oauth, etc, then the user passes their credentials to the security server (e.g. Active Directory, ADFS, IdentityServer, etc) which authenticates them and issues a token. They then provide the token to the app in the header of every request. The app checks the token with the security server each time.

Comment: You can see how companies like Google use OAuth to provide access to their APIs as an example of such a pattern. See https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2. Microsoft has lots of documentation regarding ADFS and associated technologies.  Ultimately though this is a fairly complex topic and not something you want to get wrong. If you're unsure, hire a web security expert.

Comment: Yes. I'd use openid/oauth using the client credentials/application flow, and issue the 3rd party with a set of client credentials to authenticate with. Just did this with openiddict.